# Excel is mixing up cell contents when using SUM and SUMIF

Tags: excel, sum, formula

I might be misunderstanding how Excel's SUM and SUMIF functions work.  I'm using the formula `=SUM(SUMIF(OctDSPB,"70",OctDYen),SUMIF(OctDSPB,"80",OctDYen),SUMIF(OctDSPB,"90",OctDYen),SUMIF(OctDSPB,"100",OctDYen),SUMIF(OctDSPB,"141",OctDYen),SUMIF(OctDSPB,"315",OctDYen),SUMIF(OctDSPB,"501",OctDYen),SUMIF(OctDSPB,"527",OctDYen),SUMIF(OctDSPB,"0B6",OctDYen),SUMIF(OctDSPB,"0E3",OctDYen))` in order to add the lookup values in a dynamic list that may or may not contain that information.  However, included in the named range is the value "0E8" and using that formula excel considers it the same as "0E3" and includes it in the calculation.  These are values that I cannot change and so I need to find a way to prevent excel from including the unwanted calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `0E3` and `0E8` are interpreted as E notation, i.e. as equaling `0`. This issue seems to arise from `SUMIF` treating your text in `OctDSPB` as numbers (e.g. `SUMIF(OctDSPB,"70",OctDYen)` and `SUMIF(OctDSPB,70,OctDYen)` would be equivalent).

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` and also simplify your formula.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((OctDSPB={"70","80","90","100","141","315","501","527","0B6","0E3"})*OctDYen)
```

Example with sample data:

[image]

Comment: @KyleThomas - no problem. I'm guessing this is an unfortunate side effect of `SUMIF` trying to be helpful.